# Issue with sass-loader in a new project created with vue cli

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, sass-loader

I have the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                      16:19:53

 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\xampp\htdocs\new-project\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:88:29)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\new-project\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-415 14:3-18:5 15:22-423
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.16.12.87:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=469af010&scoped=true&lang=scss&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\xampp\htdocs\new-project\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:88:29)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\new-project\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=469af010&scoped=true&lang=scss& 4:14-464 14:3-18:5 15:22-472
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=469af010&scoped=true&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.16.12.87:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I see it in all my Vue.JS projects.

I've seen all the possible solutions online... nothing works.

Comment: Does node-sass is installed ?

Comment: Yes, it's installed.

Comment: Which version of sass-loader are you using ?